# Assigning different Java versions to different Web Apps on client wkst

Tags: java

Can/is it possible to open different web apps each calling different java versions? Two web apps that clients browse to via favorites link in IE6 need older versions of java to display properly.

Comment: What do you mean by web app? Servlets? If so, are you talking about different Java versions on the server?

Comment: And do you really need different version of Java? Or just different versions of your Java application code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, so let me rephrase :

You have webapps that need to execute Java code on the client. So probably via an Applet or maybe Java Web Start.

For applets, you can specify the Java "family" as specified in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/family-clsid.html

For JWS, you can specifiy the Java version in the JNLP file. Soory, I dont have the docs at hand ...

If I misunderstood your problem, please rephrase it and I'll try to have a second answer ...

Comment: Workstation connects to vendor webserver via IE6 browser to use an Java enabled webpage to conduct buisness, two different vendors, two different webpages that require different versions of Java to veiw and interact with the webpage, how does one make it so when the client machine browses to one vendor site it will use the version of Java required for it while also useing the correct version for the other webpage when the client browses to it to interact? I have no control on the vendors webpage and scrpits/java versions used on their web servers or web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Java Web Start allow you to specify the exact java version you want to use, in the JNLP-file.